# Menu Widget displays all menu items when viewing blog post

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I have a menu widget placed when a certain part of the website is accessed (In my case, a section called "Media Center" which is accessed at ~/media-center). This section also contains pages below it, such as "/media-center/videos".

I have the layer rule for this set up as "url("~/media-center*")" and works perfectly and as expected while viewing any pages that I have set up with permalinks to match.

However, I also am wanting a blog to work as a News section, which would be accessed at "~/media-center/news".

The menu widget displays fine when viewing the blog page, however when I go to visit a blog post, the menu widget displays all other (outside of my media center node) items.

Does anyone know why this happens and if there is a way to prevent it?  Is it a bug?  Thanks!

*Just to clarify:  when accessing ~/media-center/news the menu widget displays correctly. However when I go to a blog post, such as ~/media-center/news/new-blog-post, all menu items from other nodes display.

Comment: The question still isn't clear.

Comment: What do you mean by "nodes"? Menu widget displays a given menu. By using layers you just tell on which pages the widget has to appear or not. It does not affect/filter the menu items in any way.